# Add attributes like id to block level elements in CKEditor?

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

In Drupal 8, is there a way/module to add attributes like "id" to h1-h6, p, span and so forth?

I am trying to find a way to support anchors, which Drupal does not seem to support anymore.

edit: Yes, I can instruct to edit with the Source button, but I am looking for a more user friendly way with a dialog and I am not seeing it.

Answer (score -1):

If you just need to add ID to a link you can use the D8 Editor Advanced link module https://www.drupal.org/project/editor_advanced_link

It basically allows you to put attributes on anchor tags without touching the source code.